# How to redirect from api call form submission in react

Tags: reactjs, redirect, antd, form-submit, ant-design-pro

```
<body>
  <form id="redirectForm" method="post" action="url">
    <input type="hidden" name="" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="" value=/>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit();
  </script>
</body>
```

I have an html file as you can see above when I open this file it redirects me to the action url with the data, If I want to do the same in React, How should I do this? I tried this

```
   <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="submit" value='submit'/>
    </form>
```

handleSubmit Function:

```
axios.post(`url`, formData)
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am using ant design and I think Forms in ant design don't work like normal forms because it didn't submit when I tried the method Nikki9696 mentioned in the comments.

Comment: if you don't want React to handle the form, just don't have a onSubmit? The submit button would then just submit the form like normal, which would post it ("redirect").

Comment: @Nikki9696 Sorry I forgot to mention a few things, but I made the changes to the question now.